# Vue : How can I add a jar library file to Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jar

I want to convert this html source as Vue. My customer provided this source and jar library file to me. Maybe I need to use `<object>` tag

If I want to use `<object>` tag  to use jar file, **1) then how can I add a jar file to Vue.js?** I think it will be not enough that just adding the jar library file to a specific directory. I know we can use java bridge like node java, But i don't know where I will locate it on Vue.js source. Or if I want to use the library then do I need to locate it to backend source?

2. **Hot to use `<object>` tag to get object** like NX of 'Test01.html' in `<template>` tag in vue.js? Can we normally use it like in normal html?
3. Can I get some information about **converting html(javascript) to Vue.js?**

**Test01.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <b>Client Test<br></b>
</head>

To use ActiveX as an object as an ID.

<object classid='clsid:ONE_UUID' id='NX'> </object> 
<script language="javascript">
    function isNDOK()
    {
        var ret01 = NX.isNDOK()
        alert(ret01)
    }
    
</script>

<body>
<form name="frm">
<APIs used when CS interlocking><br>
ND status: <input type="button" value="isNDOK" onClick="isNDOK()"><br>


</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without known where the NX class from its hard to help you.
However you could try putting them into methods and including the javascript at the top of the vuejs script.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As I know it is from activeX. Do I need to say the information more? And where can be the top of the vuejs script? Just next to template?